# How can I pass a parameter from Silverlight to an RDLC Report whilst keeping it hidden?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, azure, parameters, rdlc

I've tried using Location=0 in javascript to hide the URL address bar in a popup window hosting the ReportViewer, but for some (apparently "security") reason it doesn't work, and users of my Azure-hosted Silverlight app, some of whom are from competing companies, can guess each other's quote IDs and see who is quoting what for the same business they are all after.

I know I could encrypt the ID, but am hoping there is a more direct way to provide the ID to the ReportViewer control / ObjectDataSource in my Report.aspx file, without making it visible as a URL parameter?

Suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could call s JavaScript (jQuery powered) function on your page, providing the `ID`, then, instead of opening a plain POPUP with a `GET`, you could do a `POST` to open a new window with the report. Of course doing `POST` over `HTTPS`.

Apart from that, you concern smells badly in terms of security. Why would you even allow rendering of a `ReportViewer` if the requested parameter does not belong to the requester?

Being concerned about security you shall disable anonymous access to your app. Then you would know which user is logged. Then you can easily link a user with a quote id. Then you can easily perform a check for whether given `quote id`, or whatever parameter requested belongs to the user that requests it.

By the way, what is the `AZURE` specific here? This is general web dev question with not Azure specific.

Sample JS function to open a window with POST

```
function OpenWin(someId)
{
 var form = document.createElement('form');
 form.action = 'URL_TO_YOUR_RDLC_ASPX_PAGE';
 form.method = "POST";
 form.target = '_blank'; // this is important to open a new window
 var hiddenId = document.createElement('input');
 hiddenId.name = 'theNameOfTheParam';
 hiddenId.value = someId;
 form.appendChild(hiddenId);
 document.body.appendChild(form);
 form.submit();
}
```

You can manage the number of input fields (i.e. params to be sent) at your own will by creating addition hidden inputs.

Comment: My Domainservice has the [RequiresAuthentication] attribute

Comment: I would like to implement your suggestion, but can you tell me how I can see who the user is from the Domainservice "GetQuote" routine?  BTW There is an Initialize routine in the DomainService that sets a private _User field from the DomainServiceContext but this only runs during login and so for subsequent service calls - like GetQuote - this _User field is null.


(On reflection there is probably nothing Azure specific about the main question, but I wasn't sure if the options might be restricted by the use of Azure.  I've found that some online ReportViewer examples didn't work on Azure.)

Comment: I was also hoping there would be some kind of "Loaded" callback event on the  HTMLPopupWindow object, which would enable the Silverlight code to, for example, set the value of an invisible textbox that is read by the ObjectDataSource which supplies the data via OData to the ReportViewer control?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707361(v=vs.91).aspx) and [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942451(v=vs.91).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for those links but I can only see how to restrict access at the server by role membership - not by identifying the actual user as you suggested.  And knowing who the user is at the client is no use because again - they might try to change the UserID in the URL that loads the Report.aspx.  But your other suggestion also seems a good idea - Can you suggest a link for help on how to use POST to open a new window with the report?  (I'm good with SQL, new to Web prog!)

Comment: for having a POST to a new windows - look updated answer. For rest - consult a WebDev. What you request is not a matter of single question and answer, but a matter of understanding web technology (ASP.NET in particular + Silverlight).

Comment: This finally hid the address bar:  HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(GetReportURL()), "_blank", "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");  Your suggestions were most helpful - Thank you.

I had thought I got close with Invoke to run a script inside my ReportViewer webform.aspx to set the QuoteID.  

But they don't tell you it won't work if the webform.aspx is not the one hosting your Silverlight app.  So you waste hours and hours..

Comment: Oops - but not in Azure!  So I ended up having to use your OpenWin function.  N.B. Two things 1. the last but one line needs to be document.body.appendChild(form); 2. The ReportViewer.aspx code-behind Page_Load needs to extract the parameters from Request.Form instead of Request.QueryString

Comment: code sample updated accordingly.
Great, you are now moving step by step to mastering Web Development!

Comment: Bad news - now I've deployed to the real Azure and it says: "Failed to Invoke: OpenWin".  However it works fine in the test 127.0.0.1 environment!  If it helps:  I've created a user account for you: User: astaykov Pwd: astaykov  http://c366a2f51815411fa021661c6ea47aa9.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Just select an Estimate and click the Print button.